# Make Foreach loop run untill it finds results

Tags: c#, razor, foreach

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
{

    var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE date = '" + inputDate + "'";
    sumKG = 0;
    foreach (var c in db.Query(getData))
    {
        var total = c.kg * c.rep * c.sett;

        DateTime thisDay = c.date;
        nextDay = thisDay.AddDays(1);

        inputDate = nextDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        sumKG += total;
    }
    @sumKG <br />
}
```

So this does a calculation for each row in the database with the same date stored to it, when the foreach loop is done with the calculation it jumps back to the for loop and `inputDate` will be the following day because of `addDays(1)`, however, if there is a date that does not match anything in the database it does nothing, I want it to add one day again to `inputDate` and continue to the next day each time there is no match until for `for` loop is done!

Because the point of the `for loop` in this case is to check data for one months time, and when one day is zero, it just stops, how do I solve this? Did it make any sense?

Comment: Why do this calculation in c# for each day, instead of using sql to calculate it all in the first place? If you will add your table structure, some sample data and desired result, we can probably help you create a single sql statement that will calculate it all for you.

Comment: You should try to keep this kind of logic seperate from the viewmodel. Do all your calculations in the controller and present the results in the viewmodel.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I didn't think about that haha, but I fixed that now! I actually knew how to do that hehe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the date you are searching on because you have it outside of the foreach loop. Therefore the logic for adding a day should be done outside the foreach loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
{

var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE date = '" + inputDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
sumKG = 0;

nextDay = thisDay.AddDays(1);
inputDate = nextDay

foreach (var c in db.Query(getData))
{
    var total = c.kg * c.rep * c.sett;
    sumKG += total;
}
@sumKG <br />
}
```

This is also more efficient because you are not resetting variables unnecessarily - It will however require you to make inputDate a DateTime and not a string.

Or better yet, why do you need 31 database queries?

Unfortunately I do not have the tools with me to give you the SQL command, but it is definitely possible to write a command that can calculate the sumKG for a range of rows between inputDate and inputDate + 31 days, and then return the result in the format of: Grouped Date | sumKG

If you like the idea of 1 SQL command returning 31 rows of totals, then you may want to head over to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql for help

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll look in to that, making it only one query! But this also solved my problem for now so this is the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
{

  var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE date = '" + inputDate + "'";
  sumKG = 0;
  foreach (var c in db.Query(getData))
  {
     var total = c.kg * c.rep * c.sett;
     sumKG += total;
  }
  inputDate = inputDate.AddDays(1);
  @sumKG <br />
}
```

Comment: This example will not work as Pontus's input Date is of type string. Although I understand your approach and that looks good...